# How do I solve $\int_0^1 \frac {\ln \frac {x^2 + \sqrt 3 x +1} {x^2 - \sqrt 3 x + 1}} x dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, education

I don’t know how to solve this integral. Can someone give me a step-by-step solution to this, explaining how to get to the exact result, please?
PS: The answers given in the other question may not correspond to what my teacher is asking.

Comment: Is this homework? If so please state that.

Comment: use partial fractions.